# change all the elements of my array repeating the last one I added

Tags: javascript

when I try to add the new element to the array it changes the rest of the elements by repeating the last one I added
I'm learning to program in java script and I found this error not because it occurs can someone explain it to me

```
input=`^>v<`
input=input.split("")
var coordinates=[0,0]
var positions=[]
y=0
v=0

for (x in input){
    v+=1
    x=input[x]
  
    
     if (x=="^"){
        coordinates[1]+=1
     }
     if (x=="v"){
        coordinates[1]-=1
     }  
     if (x==">"){
        coordinates[0]+=1
     }
     if (x=="<"){
        coordinates[0]-=1
     }
    boolean=positions.indexOf(coordinates)
    positions.push(coordinates)
    console.log(coordinates)
      }
   
    
     
     
    console.log(positions)
```

**output**

```
[ [ 0, 1 ] ]
[ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ]
[ [ 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0 ] ]
[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]
[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: [don't use `for...in` on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in).

Comment: You're pushing the same `coordinates` array every time through the loop. You need to create a new array each time. `push()` doesn't make a copy.

Comment: what i can use ? for each

Comment: in each loop the value of coodinates is diferent  why need create the new arry?

Comment: [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or just a basic [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or any of the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods of which [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is one.